# Do different version of NPM change the contents of a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When performing an `npm install` with different versions of NPM does the contents of a modules directory within `node_modules` differ in any way?

Comment: Put simply: No.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially.

NPM v3 introduced a flatter directory structure for dependencies than previously used, largely because the v2 structure could break Windows file name length restrictions.

More details are here: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

I'm not aware of anything changing other than this, however packages can change their structure between releases.